# How to solve error LNK1112 when converting a x86 project to x64?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, mfc, 64-bit

I'm converting my x86 MFC dll code to x64 on Visual Studio 2015 and I'm getting the error message:

> .\Debug\FabricaPesquisa.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

I already checked the **Target Machine** on Linker and it is correct (MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64)), my **"Additional Options"** is blank (apparently wrong information here can cause the same error), the **Configuration Manager** it is referencing the correct platform, the libs added on **"Additional Dependencies"** are all x64 ( I also tried removing them and it didn't change the error).

When I used **dumpbin** in my **.obj** files (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528235/4246164)) I noticed that all of them are machine (x86).

I also followed the steps [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364020/4246164), making sure that the paths in **"Executable Directories"** are referencing x64 directories:

> $(VSInstallDir)
>
> $(VSInstallDir)bin
>
> $(VSInstallDir)bin\x86_amd64
>
> $(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)

How can I solve this problem?

*Thanks in advance and any hint will be appreciated!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone goes through the same problem, apparently, I didn't pay enough attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364020/4246164) and didn't realize that the order of the entries matters,

to work it's necessary to put **$(VCInstallDir)\bin\x86_amd64** before of **$(VCInstallDir)\bin** in the **Project Properties > VC++ Directories > Executable Directories**.